# feinstein's SlidingMenu library, Define BehindContentView in every activity?

Tags: android, slidingmenu, code-duplication

I am using feinstein's SlidingMenu library, I want to use the SlidingMenu in every activity i have. Should I have to write the SlidingMenu code in every activty?!, or can I write the slidingMenu in a class and start calling the class in every activity or is there any other way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way would be to work with fragments. Add the drawer to your `MainActivity extends FragmentActivity`. Then add and remove fragments instead of switching activities.

Also, there's no need to use SlidingMenu anymore, Google added their own implementation, called NavigationDrawer to the Support Library. See http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply create an abstract Activity that does that feature. than, each Activity will extend that basic abstract activity and you'll have the same behavior for them all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but correct me if i am wrong, I just can declare the functions that i need to use within the abstract but i still need to write the code of the functions within each activity. right?